# Wrong list output than what was expected

Tags: python, list

So I have to iterate through this list and divide the even numbers by 2 and multiply the odds by 3, but when I join the list together to print it gives me [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0]. I printed each value inside the loop in order to check if it was an arithmetic error but it prints out the correct value. Using `lambda` I have found out that it rewrites `data` every time it is called, so I'm trying to find other ways to do this while still using the `map` function. The constraint for the code is that it needs to be done using a map function. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
data_list1 = []
i = 0
while i < len(data):
    if (data[i] % 2) == 0:
        data_list1 = list(map(lambda a: a / 2, data))
        print(data_list1[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        data_list1 = list(map(lambda a: a * 3, data))
        print(data_list1[i])
        i += 1
print(list(data_list1))1
```

Edit: Error has been fixed.

Comment: I'd recommend some basic debugging - at the very least, put `print`s in to see what's happening. It should be a clue that all numbers get divided by 2.

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Have a look at this post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: You use the lambda function on the entire array, thus it changes everything and not only the even ones. and your printing shows only the desired index which correspond to `True` in the condition

Comment: @DavidS oh ok that makes sense, thanks! I'll try some other way then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way for me to do this is as follows:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
data_list1 = []
i = 0
for i in range(len(data)):
    if (data[i]%2) == 0:
        data_list1=data_list1+[int(data[i]/2)]
    elif (data[i]%2) == 1: # alternatively a else: would do, but only if every entry in data is an int()
        data_list1=data_list1+[data[i]*3]
print(data_list1)
```

In your case a for loop makes the code much more easy to read, but a while loop works just as well.

In your original code the issue is your map() function. If you look into the documentation for it, you will see that map() affects every item in the iterable. You do not want this, instead you want to change only the specified entry.

Edit: If you want to use lambda for some reason, here's a (pretty useless) way to do it:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
data_list1 = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    if (data[i] % 2) == 0:
        x = lambda a: a/2
        data_list1.append(x(data[i]))
    else:
        y = lambda a: a*3
        data_list1.append(y(data[i]))    
print(data_list1)
```

If you have additional design constraints, please specify them in your question, so we can help.

Edit2: And once again onto the breach: Since you added your constraints, here's how to do it with a mapping function:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def changer(a):
    if a%2==0:
        return a/2
    else:
        return a*3
print(list(map(changer,data)))
```

If you want it to be in a new list, just add `data_list1=list(map(changer,data))`.

Hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! Edit2 makes a lot of sense, I tried doing something like this in the beginning but my formatting was incorrect (using two functions for each task and putting that into an individual map).

Comment: I'm happy I could be of help. Generally speaking I'd recommend always looking into the documentation of the used functions, most of the time it's the most time efficient way to fix your issues. Good luck with your python learning journey.

Answer (score 0):

From your latest comment I completely edited the answer below (old version can be found in the edit-history of this post).

---

From your update, I see that your constraint is to use `map`. So let's address how this works:

`map` is a function which exists in many languages and it might be surprising to see at first because it takes a *function* as an argument. One analogy could be: You give a craftsmen (the "map" function) pieces of metal (the list of values) and a tool (the function passed *into* "map") and you tell him, to use the tool on each piece of metal and give you back the modified pieces.

**A very important thing to understand** is that `map` takes a complete list/iterable and return a new iterable all by itself. `map` takes care of the looping so you don't have to.

- If you hand him a hammer as tool, each piece of metal will have a dent in it.
- If you hand him a scriber, each piece of metal will have a scratch in it.
- If you hand him a forge as tool, each piece of metal will be returned molten.

The core to underand here is that "map" will take any list (or more precisely an "iterable") and will apply whatever function you give it to *each* item and return the modified list (again, the return value is not really a list but a new "iterable").

So for example (using strings):

```
def scribe(piece_of_metal):
    """
    This function takes a string and appends "with a scratch" at the end
    """
    return "%s with a scratch" % piece_of_metal

def hammer(piece_of_metal):
    """
    This function takes a string and appends "with a dent" at the end
    """
    return "%s with a dent" % piece_of_metal

def forge(piece_of_metal):
    """
    This function takes a string and prepends it with "molten"
    """
    return "molten %s" % piece_of_metal


metals = ["iron", "gold", "silver"]
scribed_metals = map(scribe, metals)
dented_metals = map(hammer, metals)
molten_metals = map(forge, metals)

for row in scribed_metals:
    print(row)


for row in dented_metals:
    print(row)


for row in molten_metals:
    print(row)
```

I have delibrately *not* responded to the core of your question as it is homework but I hope this post gives you a practical example of using `map` which helps with the exercise.

#### Another, more practical example, saving data to disk

The above example is deliberately contrived to keep it simple. But it's not very practical. Here is another example which could actually be useful, storing documents on disk. We assume that we hava a function `fetch_documents` which returns a list of strings, where the strings are the text-content of the documents. We want to store those into `.txt` files. As filenames we will use the MD5 hash of the contents. The reason MD5 is chosen is to keep things simple. This way we still only require one argument to the "mapped" function and it is sufficiently unique to avoid overwrites:

```
from assume_we_have import fetch_documents
from hashlib import md5

def store_document(contents):
    """
    Store the contents into a unique filename and return the generated filename.
    """
    hash = md5(contents)
    filename = '%s.txt' % hash.hexdigest()
    with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(contents)
    return filename


documents = fetch_documents()
stored_filenames = map(store_document, documents)
```

The last line which is using `map` could be replaced with:

```
stored_filenames = []
for document in documents:
    filename = store_document(document)
    stored_filenames.append(filename)
```

Comment: Could I keep the lambda if I added each element into a separate list and then join it? I know it's not the most efficient way to do it but I kinda not allowed to use other thing.

Comment: Updated! Idk if I need to use lambda but I tried creating an outside function with the math and then performing it but it didn't work. I don't really know what the limitations are on the map function but could doing the if statement inside the map also work? pulling this from things you can do in java.

Comment: yikes... many typos (including in the call of `map`)... They are fixed now :)

Comment: I see, great analogy by the way! So what is the difference in: `map(metals, forge)` and `map(forge, metals)`? Edit: nvm saw the updated typos XD

Comment: One is correct, the other is wrong (that was the typo). `map` takes a function as first argument. Not a list of values. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer and also teaching me how `map` works, I'll be sure to not forget that!

Comment: I've added a more practical example, which should give you another perspective at `map` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the string for the output like this:

`print(','.join(["%2.1f " % (.5*x if (x%2)==0 else 3*x) for x in data]))`

Comment: Wow I don't really know how that works, but it's very nice formatting I do have to say.

Comment: I've updated the answer to take that math into account :-)

Comment: @RodrigoL if you are learning Python, I would refrain from using code like this. Especially when working in a team. While it is a short one-liner it is hard to debug with a debugger and hard to read with someone not experienced with the language. Convoluted one-liners like this are "cool" but detrimental for code-readability in the long-term.

Comment: @exhuma thanks for the tip, I would never try to do this at my current level but it's exciting to know that maybe one day I will understand that and how it works.

Comment: @RodrigoL ... and that's the point why you should refrain from ever writing lines like this. Yes they are *exciting*, but if you work on a team, a junior-dev might join in some day and be in a position like you right now and might not understand those lines. This hampers productivity over-all.

Comment: @exhuma ah ok, yes that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I kindly want to disagree. The idiom `[func(a) for a in arr]` is very readable and a good way to write simple loop structures in an elegant way. However, I agree that this specific one-liner is a bit too long, splitting up in two or three lines would be a bit clearer.